# How can I drop indexes created by auto indexing?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I have been trying the Auto Indexing Feature in ADW. What is the procedure to drop the auto-indexes on ADB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DBMS_AUTO_INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_AUTO_INDEX.html#GUID-A40B3A11-4571-46CE-9B12-563F46CC2B0A) package to drop the indexes created by Auto Indexing.

An example, copied from the doc, is:

```
exec dbms_auto_index.drop_auto_indexes('SH','"SYS_AI_612ud3j5ngf0c"',TRUE);
```